# WP7 how to use MediaPlayerLauncher with song in library

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player, launcher

[This article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/5-how-to-use-mediaplayerlauncher-in-a-wp7-app) says that

> MediaPlayerLauncher launches the Media Player application and plays
>   the specified  media file. Media files are stored in isolated storage
>   or in the application's installation directory.

However, I want to select songs from a certain album from library (using `MediaLibrary`) and launch the default Media player to play it. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't do that with the current API.

The MediaPlayerLauncher takes a parameter of type 
[MediaLocationType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.medialocationtype%28v=vs.105%29.aspx),
and from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) we can see that there's no option to access the media library

> Use MediaLocationType.Data for media files that are stored in isolated storage. Use MediaLocationType.Install for media files that are part of the application project. They are bundled into the .xap file and stored in the installation directory of the application.

I've created a [UserVoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3721632-mediaplayerlauncher-for-media-library) request for this feature. Hopefully we'll get it with the next update if enough people vote for it.